# log4net is single threaded?

Tags: log4net, appender

Reading the docs on log4net, I noticed that all the std Appenders are labeled as

"not safe for multithreaded operations"

This makes it sound like none of the Appenders can be used in ASP.Net or a multi-threaded client.

Am I mis-reading this?  Has anyone encountered problems with threaded log4net Appenders??

Thanks --- Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Log4Net FAQ](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/release/1.2.0.30316/doc/manual/faq.html#thread-safety):

> **Is log4net thread-safe?**
>
> Yes, log4net is thread-safe.

I have used log4net in many ASP.NET applications without any problems getting a logger with:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyLogger));
```